# Setting Expectation On Method That Returns Plain Task

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, async-await, rhino-mocks

I'm struggling with the proper way to mock and set expectations on a method that returns a plain (i.e. non-generic) `Task`. Let's say I have an interface called `ICanNotCode` with the following method:

```
async Task DoSomethingIncredible();
```

I'm using Rhino Mocks as my mocking framework and have been trying to write a test for a separate method that uses this interface. The expectation looks something like this:

```
canNotCodeMock.Expect(mock => mock.DoSomethingIncredible()).Return(new Task(() => { }));
```

The code compiles but whenever I run it Visual Studio it just hangs until I manually kill the task runner.

What is the right way to set expectations on methods that return `Task`? Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `Task` constructor creates a task without starting it so it would never complete. Any code that `await`s it would never move on. That's probably why your environment get stuck. If you only need a completed task so the caller could carry on use `Task.FromResult`:

```
canNotCodeMock.Expect(mock => mock.DoSomethingIncredible()).Return(Task.FromResult(-1));
```

It doesn't really matter what is actually the result because the generic `Task<int>` inherits from the non-generic `Task`.